# tkinter error missing argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Just learning python and jumped to tkinter. please help. I am getting below error:

```
File "E:\Program Files\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

and below is my python code:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = tkinter.Tk(className="Its a Full Mad Creation")
textPad = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=80)  # creates text area
def __init__(self):

    self.file_opt = options = {}
    options['defaultextension'] = '.php'
    options['filetypes'] = [('PHP files', '.php'), ('Javascript files', '.js'), ('HTML files', '.htm'), ('HTML files', '.html'), ('CSS files', '.css')]

def open(self):
    file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb', title='Select a php file', **self.file_opt)
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        textPad.insert('1.0', contents)
        file.close()
```

full code is here: http://pastie.org/private/swpihqat8eo063z2eo6fng

Comment: Where is the class ?

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/swpihqat8eo063z2eo6fng

Comment: where is the class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maybe expand on @Rockybilly 's question -- are you trying to define a class? That's what it looks like from the `__init__` function you've written, but you haven't actually put the class itself. For example, you need something that looks like:

```
class SomeClass: # This line is missing!
    def __init__(self, x):
         ... code ...
```

Comment: oh m sorry, I am just learning.. I forgot.. i thought only def will work

Comment: No worries. Just put all your associated functions under a top line like that one, and see if that works.